# Setting background image height to 100%

Tags: css, image, background, height

I've been trying to set a background image's height to 100% or auto, but when I do this, the image is simply not shown by any browser. Can't figure out a reason for this. It keeps me from making decent responsible images.

The code is the following:

```
<div class="responsive_image" />
```

And the CSS is the following:

```
.responsive_image {
background-image ("testing_image.jpg");
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Again, the (frustrating) result is that the image is never shown. However, when I set the background-size height in 100px or 200px, the image is perfectly shown. Can't figure out why does it happens.

Comment: What if you used `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;`?

Answer (score 3):

First of all,  Your `background-image` is missing the `: url` after it (like this: `background-image: url('testing_image');`)

Example:

```css
.responsive_image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%; /* or better, use cover (or contain) if you don't want to stretch images */
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive_image"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you set `background-size: 100%`, what it computes into is: `background-size: 100% auto`, where `100%` refers to width, and `auto` refers to height (size itself keeping aspect ratio).

The problem is: the width is 100% of ***what***? It is a little bit tricky, because it is calculated **NOT** from the `<div class="responsive-image">`, but the `<div>`'s parent. You probably did not define width in your parent, therefore the background's width cannot be computed, therefore the background is not shown. This is why it happens.

There are many ways to "make background-image appear": use `contain`, `cover`, `px` for `background-size`; or if sizing to parent is what you actually want, give the parent a width.

Comment: Thank you all for the aswers. I've been learning about the subject and it can really be a little trick, as put by light. Actually, I've solved the problem by giving up the background-image property and using img with width and heigth in 100%. Of course this is a provisional solution: I'm going to store your answers so I can give this property another try in a near future. Again, thank you for your answers.